# Get a single entry from keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all I have a class where I create a keyvaluepair.

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    reader.Read();
    string content = reader["ContentText"].ToString();
    siteContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("contentText",content));
    siteContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("pageTitle",reader["PageTitle"].ToString()));
    siteContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("meta",reader["Meta"].ToString()));
    siteContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("menuId", reader["MenuId"].ToString()));
    siteContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("cssFile", reader["CssFile"].ToString()));
    siteContent.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("accessLevel", reader["AccessLevel"].ToString()));
    return siteContent;
}
```

is there a way without looking through it to get a value something like

```
string content =  siteContent["contentText"].ToString();
```

Thanks

Comment: What type is `siteContent`?

Comment: sorry its a keyvaluepaior<string,string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume siteContent is `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`, so you can select keyvaluepair with key "contentText" and get it's value like this

```
string content =  siteContent.First(x=>x.Key=="contentText").Value;
```

You can always store your `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` as `Dictionary<string,string>` and then use it like

```
var siteContentDict = siteContent.ToDictionary((keyItem) => keyItem.Key, (valueItem) => valueItem.Value);
string content =  siteContentDict["contentText"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store key value pair and get the value of key if you are already using dictionary then it is possible.

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in myDictionary )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`siteContent` is probably a `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`, i think it would be easier for you to use it if you convert it as a `Dictionary<string,string>` :

```
Dictionary<string, string> siteContentDict= siteContent.ToDictionary(s => s.Key, s => s.Value);
string content =  siteContentDict["contentText"];
```

You reuse this dictionary as you like to easily access to your values.